# Visual Studio 2008 Hangs in an ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on an existing ASP.NET MVC 1 application in Visual Studio 2008. When I open a view about 10-20 seconds later I can't set the focus into Visual Studio. When I click with the mouse I get a system ding. Mouse wheel will scroll the source code window. Keyboard doesn't work, but the cursor is flashing.

Doing a few SO searches I found something similar and the suggestion was to:
1) clear the ngen cache
2) Install a patch that was mentioned by Phil Haack

I've done both of these but I'm still having trouble.

Any ideas or additional information that may be needed?

In addition to ASP.NET MVC I also have VisualSVN 1.7.7 and CodeRushXpress 9.3.2 installed

Comment: I had the same problem but when upgraded my PC the problem gone.
May this problem relate to performance of your PC.
As a temporary solution clean up your desktop, drive C and configure you virtual memory and other performance changes.

Comment: With the power of Windows Home Server I'm going to revert to when I first installed the OS and drivers and start the VS install process again. Thanks for the advice.

Arnis,
I'll check out Spark for another project, but this is a brown field project that was already using the default view engine. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

https://devermind.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/visual-studio-2008-randomly-hangs-when-opening-aspx-ascx-or-master-files/

After uninstalling the “Microsoft Visual Studio Web authoring Component”, the problem seems have to have disappeared.

Comment: That's interesting. Have you tried reinstalling it to see if the problem comes back? I ended up re-paving my computer to get VS2008 to work again. All components of everything work fine now. I'm sure it was just an old dirty beta component that didn't get cleaned up.

Comment: I only uninstalled this component and now vs2008 opening aspx pages without problem.